# eÌˆ versus Ã« versus ë

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, encode

I need two PHP variables to match (`$path1` and `$path2`). I can only change one of them (`$path1`).

The variables both contain the letter `ë`, but one of them is written as `Ã«` and the other one as `eÌˆ`.

When put a utf-8 metatag in the HTML of the page, they both show as `ë`, which is good, but that doesn't change the PHP variables.

Using `utf8_encode ($path1)` doesn't seem to work.

How can I solve this?

PS: This question was raised in an earlier posted question, but because it was a different question than the one asked I reposted it.

Comment: You should dump & write the hex codes, as `eÌˆ` and `Ã«` are completely useless. (they are encoded multiple times)

Answer (score 0):

Letter with accent can be written two ways in utf-8 (both are valid)

F.ex. these prints the same:

- `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE` (U+00C5) is `"\xC3\x85"`
- `A` followed by `COMBINING RING ABOVE` (U+030A) is `"A\xCC\x8A"`

You could normalize them with [`Normalizer::normalize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php), but you need to enable the boundled `intl` package for that.

Comment: Ah now I understand! Is there any other way to Normalize it? I', on a shared hosting environment and probably not able to enable the the intl package... :(

Comment: Or is there function maybe that translates only the characters with multiple options? (I find it very difficult to understand, all this charset stuff :s)

Comment: I'm afraid, there is no other options. A simple converting wouldn't work, because the target encoding is the same as the source encoding. You could convert to other unicode charset (f.ex. utf-16) and then re-encode as utf-8, but i think the results would be identical to the source.

Comment: I tried converting it to utf-16/ISO/utf7/html entities and back, and unfortunately you are right: it doesn't change it. I also tried to Normalize the string, and as I thought and even more unfortunate: I can not install the intl package in my hosting service :( It feels I am stuck... Is there absolutely no alternative to normalize? Why is a function like "str_replace eÌˆ with Ã«" no option? In theory it would work if I have a list of all possible characters like eÌˆ, right?

Comment: In theory? Yes. But the unicode range is really wide. I think that is not a real option.

Comment: Allright. Shame, then I guess I have to accept that I cannot use too strange characters... :( Thanks for your help for all the rest though!!